# How to use dynamic namespace with type switch?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

```
declare function local:change($node) 
{ 
  typeswitch($node) 
    case element(add) return 
      local:do-something()

    default return $node 
};
let $test1 := <test xmlns="http:example.com/A">
                <add>x1</add>
                <b>x</b>
             </test>

let $test2 := <test xmlns="http:example.com/B">
                <add>x1</add>
                <b>x</b>
             </test>
```

In the typeswitch when element add, doing some further processing. Code is generic. The documents that will be sent for processing will have the same elements but namespace can be different like one in the example.

How to provide the namespace dynamically in case element.

Answer (score 3):

If you declare

```
declare namespace A = "http:example.com/A";
declare namespace B= "http:example.com/B";
```

you should be able to use

```
case element(A:add) | element(B:add)
```

at least in standard XQuery (https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#prod-xquery31-SequenceTypeUnion), I don't know whether Marklogic supports it.

I don't think sequence types allow a namespace wild card in the form of e.g. `element(*:add)` so I am not sure what to suggest for your high number of namespaces, check whether you need typeswitch and sequence type matching or whether you can't simply select `*:add` in a step of a path expression or a predicate e.g. `if ($node[self::*:add])` e.g. instead of

```
typeswitch($node) 
    case element(add) return 
      local:do-something()
    ...
```

you can use

```
if ($node[self::*:add])
then local:do-something()
else $node
```

Comment: Thanks martin. This will definitely work. But my requirement is bit different. I am not having just two documents with different namespace. The number can be more. I am looking for some generic way to do this. If I have to process say 1 million documents with 100 different namespaces, I need to union 100 elements. So looking for a way to tackle it without doing union 100 times.

Comment: @KishanAshra, I am not sure there is a way with typeswitch and sequence types, perhaps a path `*:add` or predicate `[self::*:add]` can help.

Comment: MarkLogic supports SequenceTypeUnion, but the standard only allows `element(*)` with an optional type. Sounds like `self::*:xx` is your best bet.. https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#prod-xquery31-ElementTest

Comment: @martin and @grtjn The solution ```self::*:add``` did not work. As rightly said element test just allows element(*).

Comment: @KishanAshra, I have detailed in the answer how the expression I suggested is supposed to be used, it can't be used with `typeswitch` but with `if then else`.

Answer (score 1):

One way to treat elements from different namespaces in the same way (as the same 'kind' of element), is put them into the same namespace, or into no namespace. Depending on what `local:do-something()` does, the typechecked copy might want to be empty, or to contain the original contents (as shown), or contain similarly namespace-stripped children.

```
declare function local:normalize-namespace($element){
    element { local-name($element) }  { $element/@*, $element/node() }
};

declare function local:change($node) 
{
  typeswitch(local:normalize-namespace($node)) 
    case element(add) return 
      local:do-something()

    default return $node 
};
```